# Exclude few fields in java bean from being sent in rest response - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean which I am returning as part of one of my controller methods. There are few fields in the bean that I have processing but do not want them to be returned back to the consumer. Is there a way to exclude some of the fields from being returned without having to create a new bean that only has the elements that I need to return?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring boot by default uses `Jackson` to serialise/deserialise `json`. In `Jackson`, you can exclude a field by annotating it with `@JsonIgnore`, e.g.

```
public class Bean {

@JsonIgnore
private String field1;

private String field2

//getters and setters

}
```

By doing this, `field1` of `Bean` class will not get sent in the response. Also, if this bean is used in the request, this field will not be deserialised from request payload.

[Here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html)'s the documentation for `JsonIgnore`.

Comment: How do you exclude fields from the superclass? For example, `MyClass extends Exception`, how do you exclude fields from `Exception` like `localizedMessage`, `suppressed`, `cause`, `stackTrace`, etc?